# What is Difference between cp and ditto command on OSX?

Tags: macos

I want to know what is exact difference between cp and ditto command on OSX?

What are the main points that differentiate these two commands?

Comment: `ditto` is more of an OSX-specific thing, whereas `cp` is more generic across Unix/Linux platforms.

Answer (score 18):

Actually the headlines in the man pages describe the difference:

- **cp** - copy files and directories
- **ditto** - copy directory hierarchies, create and extract archives

Further information from the man pages

- **cp**

> ```
> cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
>
> cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
>
> cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
> ```
>
> Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

- **ditto**

> ```
> ditto [-v] [-V] [-X] [<options>] src ... dst_directory.
>
> ditto [-v] [-V] [<options>] src_file dst_file
>
> ditto -c [-z | -j | -k] [-v] [-V] [-X] [<options>] src dst_archive
>
> ditto -x [-z | -j | -k] [-v] [-V] [<options>] src_archive ...
>        dst_directory
> ```
>
> In its first form, ditto copies one or more source files or directories
>        to a destination directory.  If the destination directory does not exist
>        it will be created before the first source is copied.  If the destination
>        directory already exists then the source directories are merged with the
>        previous contents of the destination.
>
> In its second form, ditto copies a file to the supplied dst_file path-
>        name.
>
> The next two forms reflect ditto's ability to create and extract ar-
>        chives.  These archives can be either CPIO format (preferred for unix
>        content) or PKZip (for Windows compatibility).  src_archive (and
>        dst_archive) can be the single character '-', causing ditto to read
>        (write) archive data from stdin (or to stdout, respectively).
>
> ditto follows symbolic links provided as arguments but does not follow
>        any links as it traverses the source or destination hierarchies.  ditto
>        overwrites existing files, symbolic links, and devices in the destination
>        when these are copied from a source.  The resulting files, links, and
>        devices will have the same mode, access time, modification time, owner,
>        and group as the source items from which they are copied.  Pipes, sock-
>        ets, and files with names beginning with .nfs or .afpDeleted will be
>        ignored.  ditto does not modify the mode, owner, group, extended
>        attributes, or ACLs of existing directories in the destination.  Files
>        and symbolic links cannot overwrite directories or vice-versa.
>
> ditto can be used to "thin" Universal Mach-O binaries during a copy.
>        ditto can also copy files selectively based on the contents of a BOM
>        ("Bill of Materials") file.  ditto preserves file hard links (but not
>        directory hard links) present in the source directories and preserves
>        setuid and setgid modes when run as the superuser.
>
> ditto will preserve resource forks and HFS meta-data information when
>        copying unless instructed otherwise using --norsrc .  Similarly, ditto
>        will preserve extended attributes and Access Control Lists (ACLs) unless
>        --noextattr or --noacl is passed.  DITTONORSRC can be set in the environ-
>        ment as an alias to --norsrc --noextattr --noacl on the command line.